# Calculate persons age on given date than select from DB Entity LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity

I have a query where I need to get and count all the job positions where the person was younger than 20 years old on the day of the employment.

I need to be more precise on the age since the code below is basic and can deviate by a year. If you could help me find a way to calculate age with something like dateDiff or some other solution. Keeping in mind that I need to do this for other ages too but this is curently my problem. Thanks.

```
CountJobPositions = (from query in queryAll
                  where query.jobPosition.StartDate.Year - query.person.DateOfBirth.Value.Year < 20
                  select query).Count()
```

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: Im using version 6.1.0

Comment: @etna697 what is the issue with your code now? what is the actual and expected behaviour?

Comment: @viveknuna the problem now is that if the person is born 1.6.1990 and started working 1.1.2020 code will say it has 30 years but in fact person is 29,5 years old

Comment: @etna697 is this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/22948984/6527049?

Comment: @viveknuna thanks. It seems to be working with 

where DbFunctions.DiffYears(query.jobPosition.StartDate, query.person.DateOfBirth) <= 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used EF6 for some time but I believe that you need to use the `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions` class. In this case, I think you would use this:

```cs
where DbFunctions.AddYears(query.person.DateOfBirth, 20) > query.jobPosition.StartDate
```

You might have to do a bit of jiggery-pokery to account for nullability but that should be basically it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working with where DbFunctions.DiffYears(query.jobPosition.StartDate, query.person.DateOfBirth) <= 20